# NameError: name 'message' is not defined. Discord bot (not rewrite)

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

This is for discord btw, and it's not the rewrite. I have tried every single way to define a message. I even went too far, and had to reinstall discord.py. I have been struggling with this issue for a week. I can't find any information online. My issue is that when I am not in a channel on discord, and writing "!solodab" (I make the commands more fun when I code, I rename them one I'm done) and you're not in a channel it will say "You are not in a channel join one" but I can't delete just one message. I have to delete at least two messages with the

```
 async for message in client.logs_from(channel, limit=int(2):
     message.append(message)
await client.delete_messages(messages)
```

I have tryed to remove the s from messages. But with no luck, i have read on the offical documentain that i only need to write

```
await client.delete_message(message)
```

but when i do that, i just get this: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined

This is the relevant code for this issue, if you need me to send you the whole file, tell me. I will be forever in debt to the person who can help me solve this issue.

```
bot_prefix = "!"

crew_role = '415914560420315137'

client = Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)





client.command(pass_context=True)
async def solodab(context, voice_channel: discord.Channel = None):


server = context.message.server
author = context.message.author

if voice_channel == None:
    voice_channel = author.voice.voice_channel
else:
    try: 
        vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
        await client.say("Håper alle er klare! Nedtelling starter snart, lurer du på noe angående denne kommandoen og hva den gjør. Skriv '!help solodab'\nEller kontakt en i crewet(!crew, for en liste av alle i crewet)")
        # create StreamPlayer
        time.sleep(1)
        player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('dabb.mp3')
        player.start()
        # disconnect after the player has finished
        print("6 sek til figger's dabber ")
        time.sleep(6)
        player.stop()
        await vc.disconnect()

        channel = context.message.channel
        messages = []
        #async for message in client.logs_from(channel, limit=int(2)):
        #   messages.append(message)
        #await client.delete_messages(messages)

        await client.say("Queuen har nå startet, skriv de tre siste tallene av server id'n så kan du se hvem som er i samme game som deg!")
        time.sleep(2)
        await client.delete_message(message)


    except:

        channel = context.message.channel

        #async for message in client.logs_from(channel, limit=int(2)):
        #   messages.append(message)
        #await client.delete_messages(messages)

        await client.say("Du er ikke i en kanal, join en!" + author.mention)
        time.sleep(1)
        await client.delete_message(message.channel)

        await vc.disconnect()
```

Comment: `message` has to be a `Message` object, the library can't infer which message you want to delete.  What message do you expect that line to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what Patrick mentioned in this comments, you did not define/create message, though the idea was there.

You can do `await client.delete_message(context.message)` to delete the message that was sent to the bot.
(Though anyone could correct me if I am wrong, since I think `context` is the Message object itself.)

If you want to delete multiple messages, you would have to fetch multiple messages first, which I had failed to find any information of how to fetch multiple messages in the documentation.

Though what I have found useful is the [purge_from](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#client) function call.
(`Ctrl + F` to search for it, if it does not redirect you to the function)

So rather than fetching mutiple messages and deleting them, you could simplify it with a
 `await client.purge_from(TargetChannel, NoOfMessagesToDelete)`

With your `TargetChannel` most likely being `context.channel`, and `NoOfMessagesToDelete` any number between 0 to 100.

(As usual, check for permissions first before attempting to delete them :v .)

Comment: `context` is an object representing the invocation context, which includes the message.  You can read more about them in [the rewrite documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks, I viewed the documentation in the `latest` section and couldn't find `context`, apparently it was inside the `rewrite` section...

Comment: Goddamn ur smart, thank you so much for the reply, Kaynn. And the client.purge_from worked like a charm!